# How to access the frontmatter using remark-frontmatter?

Tags: javascript, parsing, markdown, yaml-front-matter, remarkjs

I am trying to use the [remarkjs](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark) ecosystem to parse a file containing markdown and frontmatter, and turn it into HTML. The file could look something like this:

```
---
title: Title
---

# This is a heading
```

I managed to parse the markdown, which can be done by following the example in the GitHub README file, and I also know that there is a `remark-frontmatter` package. However, just using the package like in the [before-mentioned example](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark#example-support-for-gfm-and-frontmatter) makes it so the parser ignores the frontmatter part entirely. Of course that part shouldn't be included in the HTML, but I still want to use it. But as far as I can tell, it is not part of the output. That brings me to my question: How can I access the frontmatter using these packages? I know that it is being parsed somewhere in the process, but how can I access this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the docs to be very confusing, because the most common use-case of the `remarkFrontmatter` plugin should be to make the frontmatter accessible in the file.  However, it doesn't do this, and one has to install `remarkParseFrontmatter` to get that functionality.

Here are a couple of working versions. One is with Unified, and one is with Remark.

```
import { unified} from 'unified'
import remarkParse from 'remark-parse'
import remarkFrontmatter from 'remark-frontmatter'
import remarkParseFrontmatter from 'remark-parse-frontmatter'
import remarkStringify from 'remark-stringify'
import { remark } from 'remark';

// With Unified, which is a lower-level API that remark uses internally.

const fileOfUnified = unified()
  .use(remarkParse)
  .use(remarkStringify)
  .use(remarkFrontmatter, ['yaml', 'toml'])
  .use(remarkParseFrontmatter)
  .processSync(`---\ntitle: unified worked\n---`)

console.log(fileOfUnified.data.frontmatter); // {title: 'unified worked'}

// With Remark, which is built on top of Unified, basically by adding remarkParse and remarkStringify.

const fileOfRemark = remark()
  .use(remarkFrontmatter, ['yaml', 'toml'])
  .use(remarkParseFrontmatter)
  .processSync(`---\ntitle: remark worked\n---`)

console.log(fileOfRemark.data.frontmatter); // {title: 'remark worked'}
```

Comment: `remarkParseFrontmatter` is deprecated. Ended using `gray-matter`

Answer (score 1):

I found that if you do:

add a `name` property, like what is shown in the doc:

`remarkPlugins: [remarkFrontmatter, [remarkMdxFrontmatter, {name: 'matter'}]]`

You can get the front matter by `file.matter`.

It seems the name can be anything except for the keyword `frontMatter` -- I tried `matter`, `frontM`, etc. All works, but `frontmatter` will not work on my side.

Not sure if this is a bug.